# Rails, save record with custom id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I have need to save records in db with custom id.

```
User.create(id: 467, name: "foo")
```

But it returns to me errors: 
`Mysql2::Error - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction:`. I know this error is connected to id (because if I do `User.create(name: 'foo')` it works.

I need to say that table is empty, so no conflicts should appear.

But this what needs to be done. (I know that I'm breaking rails/ruby conventions but still)

Comment: You can create a new column called `uid` in the `users` table to set a custom id.

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for. This matter really should look how it is (unfortunately this is impossible to create no column)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Perhaps we can help you solve the meta-problem (ie you shouldn't be doing this... so we can help you find a away to achieve your goals without doing it this way).

Comment: I cannot break logic what is done before me in this project, plus we have migration issues, so I need to make it working at least somehow. And only then I will may be have time to do some refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is Rails 4:

```
User.create(:name=> 'foo').update_column(:id, 467)
```

It will require the extra database query because it is against Rails convention.

Comment: This will set the value of `:id` without checking if it already exists or not. Assuming it is still an id, it must be unique in the table.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Good point. That's the problem with setting a custom ID.